# how to check null parameter in room queries with joined tables?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I'm trying to get data using Room library with SQLite and kotlin with this query but I have 2 nullable parameters with the joined tables and I don't know how to check if they are null or not.
I want to see if they are null, then returns null and if they are not null returns the parameter but I am using this query RN and the problem is the query returns data only if all parameters (even nullable ones ) are not null.
this is my query

```
@Query(
        "SELECT " +
                "f.word AS from_word, " +
                "f.word_id as from_word_id, " +
                "f2.word AS from_word2, " +
                "f2.word_id as from_word_id2, " +
                "fl.language AS from_language, " +
                "fl.language_id AS from_language_id, " +
                "t.word AS to_word, " +
                "t.word_id AS to_word_id, " +
                "t2.word AS to_word2, " +
                "t2.word_id AS to_word_id2, " +
                "tl.language AS to_language, " +
                "tl.language_id AS to_language_id, " +
                "time, " +
                "date, " +
                "day_of_week AS dayOfWeek, " +
                "country, " +
                "city, " +
                "bookmarked " +
                "FROM word_translate_map " +
                "JOIN word AS f ON from_word_map = f.word_id " +
                "JOIN word AS t ON to_word_map = t.word_id " +
                "JOIN word AS f2 ON from_word_map2 = f2.word_id " +
                "JOIN word AS t2 ON to_word_map2 = t2.word_id " +
                "JOIN language AS fl ON f.language_map = fl.language_id " +
                "JOIN language AS tl ON t.language_map = tl.language_id "
    )
    abstract fun getAllTranslatedWords(): LiveData<List<TranslatedWord>>
```

and this is my table that I have a problem with it.

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "word_translate_map",
    primaryKeys = ["from_word_map","to_word_map"],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Word::class,
            parentColumns = ["word_id"],
            childColumns = ["from_word_map"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Word::class,
            parentColumns = ["word_id"],
            childColumns = ["to_word_map"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ],
    indices = [
        Index("to_word_map")
    ]
)
data class WordTranslateMap(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "from_word_map")
    val fromWord: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "to_word_map")
    val toWord: Long,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "from_word_map2")
    val fromWord2: Long?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "to_word_map2")
    val toWord2: Long?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "time")
    val time: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date")
    val date: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "country")
    val country: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "city")
    val city: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "day_of_week")
    val dayOfWeek: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "bookmarked")
    val bookmarked: Boolean
)
```

and also this is my model (if you need this)

```
data class TranslatedWord(
    val from_word: String,
    val from_word2: String?,
    val from_language: String,
    val to_word: String,
    val to_word2: String?,
    val to_language: String,
    val time: String,
    val date: String,
    val country: String,
    val city: String,
    val dayOfWeek: String,
    val bookmarked: Boolean
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do a dual validation on the joins, is it possible on a where to select all fields that are either null or match a condition, like:

```
WHERE (:t2 IS NULL OR :t2 = :t1)
```

My guess is you can achieve the same doing that on the join, something like:

```
JOIN word AS f ON (from_word_map = f.word_id OR from_word_map IS NULL)
```

You can perform further validations (like checking if both fields are null to indeed return a null) nesting and's.

Comment: how to know that is returning null? what will be the return of null? is it 0?

Comment: I will return the row with a null value. If you want to avoid the rows that have the null value you can check "IS NOT NULL"